# Flex not respecting max-width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a chunk of text. My headlines should go wider than the paragraph text. To make that possible I use `max-width`. The first problem is that my single word paragraph is centered. I fix it by using `width` but as soon as I do that `max-width` no longer applies. Why is that? How can I fix it?

- You can be creative, but JS solutions is a no go for me here.
- I know I can wrap elements to style them individually but I don't want to be required to add extra markup in the html.
- At a later point I may have images etc that also don't follow the paragraph width. Therefore a long term less hacky solution is better.

### Example

You need to try it on a mobile. The paragraph then refuses to scale down but keeps itself to 640px.

```css
.text {
  width: 840px;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  max-width: 640px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  /* To prevent the one word to be centered */
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <h1>
    A really very long headline indeed, to tell a story
  </h1>
  <p>
    Soufflé sesame snaps tart chocolate chupa chups candy canes jujubes. Sweet brownie cheesecake tootsie roll donut bear claw macaroon brownie jelly. Cake toffee lollipop lollipop fruitcake caramels carrot cake gingerbread chocolate. Cotton candy powder
    tiramisu liquorice brownie lemon drops pastry.
  </p>
  <p>
    One word.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can please explain a little bit what actual you need ? You want to center the text with on mobile device ?

Answer (score 1):

Surround your `<p>` tags in a `<div>`. The centering is then applied to that div, and you can align your `<p>` tags as you like. [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/zrnvd7Lx/).

Comment: *"I know I can wrap elements to style them individually but I don't want to be required to add extra markup in the html."*

Answer (score 1):

> I fix it by using `width` but as soon as I do that `max-width` no longer applies. Why is that? How can I fix it?

*Why is that?*

Because you have `align-items: center` on the container. In a column-direction container, that horizontally centers flex items.

The centering starts from the middle and works its way out equally on both sides. So when you use `max-width` with short content the text will appear centered underneath the bigger paragraph above.

But when you use `width: 400px`, the item is as long as the full length paragraph above and the content, by default, aligns left. (If you set the `p` to `text-align: center`, then your experiment would fail with or without `width: 400px`.)

```css
.text {
  width: 840px;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  max-width: 640px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

p {
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <h1>
    A really very long headline indeed, to tell a story
  </h1>

  <p>
    Soufflé sesame snaps tart chocolate chupa chups candy canes jujubes. Sweet brownie cheesecake tootsie roll donut bear claw macaroon brownie jelly. Cake toffee lollipop lollipop fruitcake caramels carrot cake gingerbread chocolate. Cotton candy powder
    tiramisu liquorice brownie lemon drops pastry.
  </p>

  <p>
    One word.
  </p>
</div>
```

*How can I fix it?*

Without JS or additional HTML containers I'm not sure it's possible because there's no left alignment for the paragraphs. They're just centering based on the length of their content up to the maximum width.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you are looking for with just `CSS`, without having to add extra HTML markup.

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x8qgtpd7/

```css
.text {
  background: #eee;
}
h1{
  padding: 0px 5vw;
  text-align: center;
}
p{
  padding: 0px 15vw;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <h1>
    A really very long headline indeed, to tell a story
  </h1>
  <p>
    Soufflé sesame snaps tart chocolate chupa chups candy canes jujubes. Sweet brownie cheesecake tootsie roll donut bear claw macaroon brownie jelly. Cake toffee lollipop lollipop fruitcake caramels carrot cake gingerbread chocolate. Cotton candy powder
    tiramisu liquorice brownie lemon drops pastry.
  </p>
  <p>
    One word.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually want the `p` to expand when it has the space to expand, but also you want it to shrink when it doesn't.

So the point is that you don't want to use `min-width` because that forces `p` to be of that width even when it has no space, as intended.

Instead you should tell the `p` to adapt to the space it has, but only up to 400px. That is achieved with `max-width`.

The code:

```
p {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this code? It doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Here's a quick [codepen](https://codepen.io/nevnein/pen/LYVyNgQ)

Comment: This is no different than what the OP already has with `max-width: 400px`. It doesn't solve the problem. https://codepen.io/sostupid555/pen/zYGwBYE

Comment: It is different, as `max-width: 400px` alone centers the one word paragraph which is what OP is trying to avoid. If the headline longer than the text is required even on mobile, just add some lateral padding to the text.